# Trying to Inherit a class has constructor with parameter - c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes and I want to inherit one of them that has a constructor with a parameter but, I get errors.

First Class:

```
class stack{
 stack(int variable){

}

...code...
};
```

Second class:

```
class Expression : public stack{

//class constructor
Expression(){

}

...code...

};
```

the errors I get...

> **In constructor 'Expression::Expression()':error: no matching function for call to 'stack::stack()'**

> **note: candidate: stack::stack(int)**

> **note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided**

> **note: candidate: constexpr stack::stack(const stack&)**

> **note: candidate: constexpr stack::stack(stack&&)**

Answer (score 0):

I have searched online I didn't find anything that helps me to resolve these errors.

but after many tries, I have found the solution...and if you have a better way to resolve these errors or to describe my solution in better words or more scientific words
please share.

**Solution:** The issue was in the syntax...The second class "Expression" that inherited from the stack class should have a constructor defined as below...

```
class Expression : public stack{

  // How the constructor should be defined.
  Expression():stack(parameter_value){

}

...code...
};
```

So, the whole code will be like:

```
class stack{
 stack(int variable){

}

...code...
};

class Expression : public stack{

  // How the constructor should be defined.
  Expression():stack(parameter_value){

}

...code...
};
```